# How to activate TypeScript verification of types?

Tags: typescript, deno

I'm trying to follow a tutorial in which this sample of code is expected to fail. But in my machine it works just fine.

```js
// example.ts

let age: number;

age = 15;
console.log(age);

age = "foo";
console.log(age);
```

This is what I see:

```
$ deno run example.ts
15
foo
```

I expected it to fail with a **TS2322** code instead.

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.23.1 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 10.4.132.8
typescript 4.7.2
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Starting in v`1.23`, by default, Deno does not type-check your code when executing it.](https://deno.com/blog/v1.23#no-type-checking-by-default)

You can type-check your code (without executing it) using the command `deno check`. You can also type-check your code before execution by using the `--check` argument to `deno run`. Here are some examples using your `example.ts` module:

```
% deno --version
deno 1.23.1 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.4.132.8
typescript 4.7.2

% cat example.ts 
let age: number;

age = 15;
console.log(age);

age = "foo";
console.log(age);

% deno check example.ts 
Check file:///Users/deno/example.ts
error: TS2322 [ERROR]: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
age = "foo";
~~~
    at file:///Users/deno/example.ts:6:1

% deno run --check example.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/example.ts
error: TS2322 [ERROR]: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
age = "foo";
~~~
    at file:///Users/deno/example.ts:6:1

% deno run --check=all example.ts
Check file:///Users/deno/example.ts
error: TS2322 [ERROR]: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
age = "foo";
~~~
    at file:///Users/deno/example.ts:6:1
```

Comment: Yes! It wasn't clear from the documentation.

Comment: @lucascavalcante If you mean [the manual page for type-checking](https://deno.land/manual@v1.23.1/typescript/overview#type-checking), then I think you're right — it's outdated since the change in behavior. If you want to be helpful, you can file an issue on GitHub to notify the maintainers that it needs to be updated.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestion. I'll do that right away!

Comment: Done: https://github.com/denoland/manual/issues/348